# Qt program crashed in malloc after window resize (Linux)

Tags: c++, linux, qt, malloc, memory-corruption

I'm developing under astra-linux (Linux 3.2.0-27-generic #43astra9)
QMake version 2.01a
Using Qt version 4.8.3 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

The program I developing update a lot of info on views. Everything works perfectly until mainwindow resize.

After resizing from time to time I have segmentation fault with call stack ending with:

```
0   __GI_raise  raise.c 64  0x7ffff3a48bf5  
1   __GI_abort  abort.c 92  0x7ffff3a4bd98  
2   __libc_message  libc_fatal.c    189 0x7ffff3a82d15  
3   malloc_printerr malloc.c    6283    0x7ffff3a8cdc6  
4   _int_malloc malloc.c    4636    0x7ffff3a8ef4f  
5   __GI___libc_malloc  malloc.c    3660    0x7ffff3a90888  
6   QByteArray::resize(int) /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4    0       0x7ffff47e107d
```

Actually it crashes in different places but on the top of the stack is malloc.

I have no real code on resize event...

I run out of all my ideas...

Comment: And where in the call stack is *your* code? What are *you* doing with the `QByteArray` object?

Comment: You need to go further down the call stack to where your code is. It is there you need to verify all your assumptions about the various variables you are modifying. First rule of debugging is: it's your code that contains the error.

Comment: It looks like you corrupt memory somewhere, so better to check you program with valgrind

Comment: As I wrote, it crashes in different places... it could be even crashed in .so, but always on malloc... If there was any problem with code - it would be crashed from time to time without resizing. But it happens only after resizing... no memory leak - checked!

Comment: If such things happen, almost always the reason is memory corruption by freeing twice, calling free with invalid data, or just overwriting arbitrary memory. Remove all code unneeded until the problem disappears. Just a guess: Do you possibly manually free objects, that are passed (and then owned) by Qt? This might be a cause.

Comment: @Yury it is not leak, it is corruption, you overrun buffer at some point

Comment: So, at least I investigated the problem. As it turned out in on for my view classes was manipulating with children position and existence in resized event. Thanks a lot for everybody, you helped to go another way of thinking!